# mongo atlas connection to AWS ECS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, mongodb-atlas, sslhandshakeexception

I have a Java API that uses Mongo Atlas but locally it works but when it goes to the cloud in the AWS ECS I get these errors:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:186) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1291) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:552) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2023-11-12 04:19:23.857  INFO 1 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ac-rrfulxj-shard-00-01.fbwwahl.mongodb.net:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:684) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/:na]
```

I already tried adding "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2","-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.0","-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.3" when starting the java application, I tried to release the port for everyoner

Comment: You said the code works locally, but are you running the same docker image locally that runs in ECS? You should try to run this as a docker container locally, using the same docker image you are deploying to ECS. If you get the same error that way, then you have a configuration issue in the docker image. If it works, then you may have a network connection issue in ECS.

Comment: Also try adding `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` for more debug info.